# Automating Scheduled Task- Running main.java file

Tags: java, shell, automation, cron, scheduled-tasks

Daily i run a job in eclipse its batch job every day 11 pm. It's a main.java file need to run java application once executed i have copy the console output log into a notepad and i save with name as log file(exmaple.log), this file has to be posted to the particular share point portal, and an automated mail should be shared to the group about the file.

I want to automate this process. Please help me out, i am new to this process, but trying to automate the process which manually executing daily basis.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please share what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you added shell and cron, i am assuming it's kind of unix.

Verify server got connectivity to SharePoint server and mailx is enabled.  If it's present you can do everything from server itself. This will be my approach.

Modify code

- To log the required data to a file. You can either use a simple file
  writer or use logging libraries.
- Upload file to share point using share point rest api. Java httpclient can be used to execute http requests.
- Use javax mail to send email. Or use native mailx unix command.

Convert java class to jar file. Schedule as cron job.

If you don't have connectivity. We have to do everything from local machine.

In that case, code should be modified to connect to server and execute remotely over ssh. Use cron or windows schedules for job management.

Comment: its not unix environment, we just maintain the project in eclipse and we will run main.java on particular of time,copying the console output as log in a notepad, then we will send a outlook mail to the group, and again we will add this file into the sharepoint portal. help in this way how to automate the process